# LoadLibrary returns 126 when loading a dll in runtime

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, dll, mfc

I'm having MFC dll file that is trying to load another dll during runtime using `LoadLibrary` function.
The code below is working fine in a console app with **MBCS character set**.
However the same code that I've used in MFC dll is not working.

The `GetLastError` is trying always returning `126` which is `Module NOT Found`.
My MFC dll is having **MBCS character set**.
I even tried putting the dll in the working directory, trying to access it using the dll name and still can't find it.
I spent hours searching for a solution but didn't solves my problem.

I tried looking the dll using **Dependency Walker** and it was loaded fine.
Is anyone has an idea?
Here is my sample snippet code:

```
HINSTANCE dllGetproc = LoadLibrary((LPCSTR)"C:\\Proj\\dev\\Soft\\Soft.FXX.dll");

if (!dllGetproc ) {
    Format(var,"Could not load the dynamic library error = %d", GetLastError());
    Log(var);
}
else {
    Log("Loaded successfully.");
}
```

Comment: Please don't just post code snippets. Post proper [mcve]s that others can actually run and use to replicate the problem.  Often, while creating the minimal example, you even find the bug yourself.

Comment: You should remove that `(LPCSTR)`. I'm not sure why you would add it, but it serves no purpose. Were the value not a `LPCSTR` then your cast would merely serve to suppress the compiler message. Which would really not help.

Comment: What happens if you call `LoadLibraryA`()?

Comment: @phi The OP *is* calling `LoadLibraryA`.

Comment: @OP  `Soft.FXX.DLL` -- If this is not a DLL you created (it seems it isn't), you can contact the authors, or do more research on what components it uses.  In addition you could mention where the DLL comes from -- maybe someone here has used it before.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie The `Soft.FXX.dll` is the one we have created. Other projects load the `Soft.FXX.dll` smoothly without any errors.

Comment: @DecryptDcode As stated in the previous comment, remove the `(LPCSTR)` cast.  Does your code compile?  Yes, we know you're claiming your settings are MBCS, but there is no real proof of it.  The proof will be if you remove that cast and you get a clean compile.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes. I already removed that `LPCSTR` cast. My code is able to compile a created dll successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the root cause now. I forgot to tell that I'm attaching the dll in my application process while doing the debugging.
The application is requiring that the `Soft.FXX.dll` should be in the same directory with it. I really thought that feeding the whole dll path to `LoadLibrary` function is enough.

Comment: It is another question, please don't ask questions in answers, instead you should edit your question or ask a new question. But as a quick answer, see the docs on `SetDllDirectory` and  `SafeDllSearchMode`

Answer (score 0):

The error code tells you that a module cannot be found. Either:

1. The library that you are trying to load cannot be found.
2. That library can be found but one if its dependencies (typically the MSVC runtime library) cannot be found.